# glibc detected memory curruption

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, crash

I have to work and create often matrices(I have to use pointers) so I made a function in C++ to allocate space for them and also make sure that the last value is set to NULL.
The application drops this error(glibc detected: memory curruption) in a specific case. Here is the code:

```
template<typename T> T *allocate(int size) {
    T *temp = new T[size];
    temp[size] = (T) NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

This works:

```
unsigned char *tmp = allocate <unsigned char> (10);
```

But this one drops the error:

```
unsigned char **tmp = allocate <unsigned char *> (10);
```

That would be the equivalent of:

```
unsigned char **tmp = new unsigned char *[10];
tmp[10] = (unsigned char *) NULL;
```

Which is good. Why would it drop me this error?

Update: Thanks for the responses. I am so blind. That's one bug. But the problem of the crash was from another part of the code but also because I was adding NULL outside the allocated space of the array.

Comment: temp[size-1] = (T) NULL;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
temp[size] = (T) NULL;
```

Size in this case is indexing the memory position AFTER the last one you allocated, change it for this:

```
temp[size-1] = (T) NULL;
```

Comment: Still having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

> `temp[size] = (T) NULL;`

is assigning to unallocated memory.

```
 T *temp = new T[size];
```

allocates from temp[0] to temp[size-1]

Comment: Still having the same problem.